# Radio buttons & drop down menus (select tag) - Get previously selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Currently, I'm saving the last selected myself, like:

```
if (window.lastToe !== undefined) {
  document.getElementById(window.lastToe + 'A').className = '';
  document.getElementById(window.lastToe + 'B').className = '';

}
window.lastToe = $("input:radio[name='toe']:checked").val();
...
```

I'm calling this piece of code thru query event bindings, a la:

```
$(".control").change(controlEvent);
```

My question is: Is there any 'deselect' event I can listen for, or get through other DOM event handlers such as `change, click, select` etc. I'd prefer not to have to save these values if there was another way to do it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is not clear...

Comment: @PraveenKumar I have updated the question. Please let me know if it's still unclear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the issue here is that I didn't think about how I could use JQuery to find the previously selected by searching for the `class` I set in `change`, and once I'd thought of that, I didn't know jQuery well enough to make it happen. But having thought of it, and having learned how to script the jQuery, I've now solved this issue.

Thanks!